# Javascript/ECMA date validation

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an issue where I am being passed DOB in a variable from another source in the format of YYYY/MM/DD but in the application the customer is then asked to input DOB in the following format YY/MM/DD.

What function in Javascript or ECMA can I use to match these dates?

I need to match the DOB or not match so I can move to the next state.  Its bad planning from my client but I need to find a way around it.

I am not a Javascript or ECMA person, so I am limited in what I can do.  I am not sure I can do anything with it at all with the difference between the 2 date formats.

Comment: I am not sure this is a duplicate of the above.  I am not just converting I am trying to match.  So throughout, I have a varcust_DOB being passed with "YYYY-MM-DD', I am then asking the customer in the application to enter their DOB in the format of 'DD-MM-YY'.

I need logic in my application to say if varDOBinput "DD-MM-YY' = 'varcust_DOB'(format YYYY-MM-DD)

Comment: this is a valid question if you are a newbie to Javascript. Sorry, not enough space to add comments.
One option is manipulate and compare as strings.

// if the date formats are in DD-MM-YY and YYYY-MM-DD
//swap around 
//get DD, MM, YY
var varDOBinput='11-01-90';  //11th Jan 1990  DD-MM-YY
var varcust_DOB='1990-01-11';    //11th Jan 1990  YYYY-MM-DD


var new_varcust_DOB=varcust_DOB.substr(8,2)+'-'+varcust_DOB.substr(5,2)+'-'+varcust_DOB.substr(2,2);

if (varDOBinput === new_varcust_DOB)
console.log('matching DOB')
else
    console.log('non matching DOB');

Comment: https://codepen.io/newschapmj1/pen/Pevoqq?editors=1111 for better view